# How to make tags listed by activity?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

let say i have two tags in my website.

one is football and the other is basketball.

and let say that i have 3 articles tagged with football and 10 tagged with basketball.

and the total comments and views on all 3 football tagged articles = 9 comments + 100 views.

while the 10 basketball tagged articles = 3 comments + 90 views.

now i want a block that lists this tags by activity

and that would be like that :

Most popular tags :

1- football (beacause 3 articles + 9 comments + 100 views = 112)

2- basketball.(beacause 10 articles + 3 comments + 90 views = 103 < 112)

thank you very much.